# Unable to run Build/Flutter/Build APK from Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I created a fresh demo project in Android Studio (Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4) using Create New Flutter Project.

When I click Build->Flutter->Build APK, I get the following error:

```
C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color build apk

 Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           909ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred starting process 'Gradle build daemon'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1
```

But I am able to run the command gradlew build from cmd prompt \Android and I am able to build the APK.

Any idea why it is not able to launch from Android Studio?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are running `flutter build apk` in wrong dir.. You should choose a project dir and the try to build apk

Comment: No, I am not running flutter build apk manually from command line. I am using the Build menu in Android Studio. In Build menu, I see Flutter submenu and then "Build APK" menu item. That is supposed to build the APK, right?
This menu item is available only when I am on the flutter project root.

Comment: but you want to build app apk so you are suppose to run the command in project dir

Comment: Ok, I understand you now. Yes, I am running it from the project directory.